# How can I modify the displayed discount message?

Tags: cividiscount

Are there any controls for the displayed discount message?

I'd like to change the message and, if possible, not show it depending on user criteria - membership, etc.

A nice to have would be to have control over the location.

I can't seem to find documentation on this extension

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation isn't complete but is available [here](https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount).  It specifically mentioned control over the location as something that doesn't exist yet.  If you're JavaScipt-savvy, a single line of jQuery will let you move the box wherever you want; a second line will let you control the wording.  I wish there was an answer for non-coders to do what you're asking for.  If this is important to you and you're not a coder, you might be able to fund someone (either the core team or another CiviCRM developer) to add those features.